# Why don't string_view and span constructors use C++20 concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, c++23

C++20 and C++23 introduce template constructors for iterator pairs and ranges for [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/basic_string_view). [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span/span) has analogous constructors.

```
template<class It, class End>
constexpr basic_string_view(It first, End last); // C++20

template<class R>
explicit constexpr basic_string_view(R&& r); // C++23
```

The documentation contains the requirements for the arguments. Why are these requirements not defined as [C++20 concept constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints)? Wouldn't that lead to much better error messages?

Comment: They very well may be implemented as concepts.  The standard tries to define the desired behavior and constraints, not necessarily how to implement those constraints or behaviors.

Comment: Note that when papers for that written concepts also has been under development. So when work on C++20 was in progress, from piratical point of view it was safer to use old approach defining requirements. This way changes in concept would not have impact on document about string_view or span. Now updates in C++23 are matter of manpower vs potential gains.

Comment: all is subject to the as if rule. When speficiation says eg "participates in overload resolution if ..." then an implementation can do anything as long as it has the desired effect

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard library specification predates concepts... by a lot. As such, it has its own approach to specifying how things need to behave. The goal of the specification is to make the semantics as clear as possible - rather than enforcing a particular technology choice. The language is constantly changing, so putting in specific choices in the specification is fairly unhelpful.

The way *constraints* on a standard library function template are spelled out is using a [*Constraints*](https://eel.is/c++draft/string.view#cons-7) clause. For that `string_view` constructor, for instance, we get:

> *Constraints*:
>
> - `It` satisfies `contiguous_iterator`.
> - `End` satisfies `sized_sentinel_for<It>`.
> - `is_same_v<iter_value_t<It>, charT>` is `true`.
> - `is_convertible_v<End, size_type>` is `false`.

This'll surely be implemented using concepts and a `requires` clause (two of these things are concepts, after all), but the goal of the specification is to simply state *what* the constraints are, rather than *how* they will be evaluated. And this, pretty clearly, does that.

Before C++20, would you have wanted to see `std::enable_if` in the specification? Obviously not. Likewise, we don't have a Contracts language feature yet, but standard library functions do still have preconditions and postconditions - so those are laid out similarly in *Preconditions* and *Postconditions* clauses. When we get Contracts, those won't change, even if the implementations of them do.

See also [Walter Brown's paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0788r3.pdf) which clarified a lot of how standard library wording is done - splitting up the one *Requires* clause we used to have into *Constraints* (to remove from overload resolution) and *Mandates* (to issue a diagnostic).

---

There is a notable exception to this rule - where there are many standard library algorithms which are specified using concepts, specifically. This is for two reasons: either (1) they specifically need the guarantees for overload resolution that concepts provide or (2) they use concepts to additionally bring in other semantic requirements on the algorithm (since concepts have both syntactic and semantic requirements). If neither of these hold (as is the case for the `string_view` and `span` constructors asked about in the question), there isn't any specific motivation to use concepts - so a *Constraints* clause is sufficient.

Comment: These do need the `contiguous_iterator` semantic requirements (hence the _Preconditions:_ models stuff). I'm not sure there's a good reason not to use `contiguous_iterator It, size_sentinel_for<It> End`.